# Limit MySQL results by left join

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL query that creates an aggregate of data for an object and all of it's children in a one to many relationship. My query looks like this:

```
select * from object o
left join event e on o.tenant_id = e.tenant_id AND o.udid = e.udid
left join event_type et on e.event_type_id = et.event_type_id
left join event_custom_field ecf on e.event_id = ecf.event_id
left join profile p on o.tenant_id = p.tenant_id AND o.udid = p.udid
left join status s on o.tenant_id = s.tenant_id AND o.udid = s.udid
left join o_tenant_app ota on o.tenant_id = ota.tenant_id AND o.udid = ota.udid
left join tenant_app ta on ota.tenant_app_id = ta.tenant_app_id
left join heartbeat h on o.tenant_id = h.tenant_id AND o.udid = h.udid
where o.tenant_id = 'a'
AND o.checked_out = false
and p.name in ('test')
and s.status_name in ('stat1', 'stat2')
order by o.udid, e.event_id;
```

I need to be able to apply a limit to the number of objects returned while still including all of the other joined data. If I put the limit at the end then I will lose object data. I could do this on my first line:

```
select * from (select * from object limit 0,5) o
```

but that will show fewer than 5 objects if those first 5 objects don't match the where clause. I would like to do this as performant as possible as I will likely have millions of records to query against.